# Unable to deploy on Android with QT

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I am trying to use QT to develop android apps. I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and my kit is

- qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.7.1
- NDK is android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64
- SDK is from android-studio-ide-171.4443003-linux

I am able to build a sample code but trying to deploy I get the following error marked in bold

```
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/prajosh/Project/cpp_study/test_1/build-test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_1-Debug/android-libtest_1.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/prajosh/Project/cpp_study/test_1/build-test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_1-Debug/android-build/
  Application binary: /home/prajosh/Project/cpp_study/test_1/build-test_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_1-Debug/libtest_1.so
  Android build platform: android-27
  **Install to device: No
Cannot find template directory /home/prajosh/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
20:27:26: The process "/home/prajosh/Android/Qt5.7.1/5.7/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 3.
Error while building/deploying project test_1 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.1))
When executing step "Build Android APK"**
20:27:26: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Tried installing gradle but gives me an error

```
**java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jni/libnative-platform-curses.so: undefined symbol: tgetent**
```

Could not get a correct solution after searches. Could anyone kindly, please point me the mistake?

Comment: Show your .pro file

Comment: This was fixed in Qt 5.10 I believe. Either upgrade or go through the painful process of downloading the templates and copying them to the SDK folder, which they will get deleted each time you update the SDK.

Comment: I see that Qt has an android release for 5.8 and not for 5.10. Am I missing some thing here?